# Print a trapezoid in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to output a trapezoid after setting the number of rows, and the width of the base of the trapezoid. Currently, it works in certain cases but not in others.

In this example, It works

```
Enter height: 5
Enter width: 16

     @@@@@@@@
    @@@@@@@@@@
   @@@@@@@@@@@@
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

In this one, it does not

```
Enter height: 5
Enter width: 14

     @@@@@@@
    @@@@@@@@@
   @@@@@@@@@@@
  @@@@@@@@@@@@@
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

What am I doing wrong? this is my code:

```
public void printTrapezoid(Scanner sc)
{
    int width;
    int rows;

    System.out.print("Enter height: ");
    rows = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter width: ");
    width = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("");

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = rows - i; j > 0; j--)
        {
          System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < (width / 2) + (2 * i); j++)
        {
          System.out.print("@");
        }

        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: *"In this one, it does not"* What, *specifically*, is wrong? And what did you see when you stepped through the code with the debugger built into your IDE? (Using a debugger is **not** an advanced technique; it's a fundamental skill every beginner should learn immediately after writing "Hello, World".)

Comment: I'd recommend replacing `System.out.print("\n")` and `System.out.println("")` with `System.out.println()`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, I should have specified, the bottom row should have 14 @ symbols, as specified by the width, but it has 15. I would change it to this `for (int j = 0; j < ((width-1) / 2) + (2 * i); j++)` but that still wouldn't work. I understand the debugger, it counts to 15. Which is the problem.

Comment: So why doesn't `Enter width: 14` put 14 symbols on the bottom? That's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd keep it simple: You want to knock off two blocks for each row prior to the base, so I'd probably count `i` from `rows - 1` to `0` (inclusive):

```
for (int i = rows - 1; i >= 0; --i)
```

and in the loop subtract two blocks for each `i`:

```
int blocks = width - i * 2;
```

Since we only need to print out one space (rather than two, the trailing space is implied) per row, and since we're counting `i` backward, we just output `i` spaces.

So:

```
public void printTrapezoid(Scanner sc)
{
    int width;
    int rows;

    System.out.print("Enter height: ");
    rows = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter width: ");
    width = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println();

    for (int i = rows - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        int blocks = width - i * 2;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
          System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < blocks; ++j)
        {
          System.out.print("@");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("");
}
```

which outputs the following for 5 / 14:

```
    @@@@@@
   @@@@@@@@
  @@@@@@@@@@
 @@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

and this for 5 / 16:

```
    @@@@@@@@
   @@@@@@@@@@
  @@@@@@@@@@@@
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Comment: That makes sense. I should have seen it. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works.

Main changes: It is much easier to think of code when you start with row 1 not row 0.  Made a small change to the for loop where starting at 1, and <= rows.

Second change was changing the way you print X values.  Using Collections.nCopies and String.join.  This is easier to follow and you do not have to worry about /2 for int, and weird row numbers...

```
public void printTrapezoid(Scanner sc)  {
    int width;
    int rows;

    System.out.print("Enter height: ");
    rows = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter width: ");
    width = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("");

    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        System.out.print(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(rows - i, " ")));
        System.out.println(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(width - 2 * (rows - i), "@")));
    }

    System.out.println("");
}
```